# How to renew the Root CA Certificate on Microsoft Active Directory Enterprise CA

Tags: certificate-authority

How to renew the Root CA certificate on Microsoft Active Directory Enterprise Root Certificate Authority Windows Server 2012 R2?

The certificate expired on 27 Aug. 2023, getting the error below while renewing. I have the updated registry to increase it from 2 to 5 Years, but no luck same error.

```
Event ID : 58 and 22
Source : Certification Authority
A certificate in the chain for CA certificate 0 for %Server-Name%-CA has expired.  A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file. 0x800b0101 (-2146762495).
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by renewing CA certificate under certificate console certsrv.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/187205)